# Workbook Referencing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reference two different workbook in two different variables but they are not working as it should be

Ex:

```
        dim TrgWb  as workbook
        dim SrcWb as workbook
        dim TrgSh  as worksheet
        dim SrcSh as worksheet

        Set TrgWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\us\Documents\test1.xlsx")
        Set TrgSh = TrgWb.Sheets(1)
        Set SrcWb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\us\Documents\History\test2.xls")
        Set SrcSh = SrcWb.Worksheets(1)
```

so object  [ Trgwb ] should refer to test1.xlsx and object [ SrcWb ]  refer to test2.xls
but actually what is happening is both of them referring to test2.xls

I don't know where is my mistake

Thanks In Advance
Sayed

Comment: Before opening either of the workbooks you need to first test whether they're already open.  Otherwise there's a risk `TrgWb` and/or `SrcWb` will be assigned to the wrong workbook.

Comment: ...basically if you call (eg) `Set wb = workbooks.open(pathHere)` and the workbook is already open, you get back a reference to the *last-opened workbook*, which may be the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

Before opening either of the workbooks you need to first test whether they're already open. Otherwise there's a risk `TrgWb` and/or `SrcWb` will be assigned to the wrong workbook.

...basically if you call (eg) `Set wb = workbooks.open(pathHere)` and the workbook is already open, *you get back a reference to the last-opened workbook*, which may be the wrong one.

You could modify your code like this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim TrgWb  As Workbook, SrcWb As Workbook
    Dim TrgSh  As Worksheet, SrcSh As Worksheet

    Set TrgWb = GetWorkbook("C:\Users\us\Documents\", "test1.xlsx")
    Set TrgSh = TrgWb.Sheets(1)
    
    Set SrcWb = GetWorkbook("C:\Users\us\Documents\History\", "test2.xls")
    Set SrcSh = SrcWb.Worksheets(1)

End Sub

'get a reference to a workbook which may already be open
'Note: does not check if the already-open wb has the same path as `path`
Function GetWorkbook(path As String, wbName As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next  'ignore error if wb not open
    Set GetWorkbook = Workbooks(wbName)
    On Error GoTo 0       'stop ignoring errors
    If GetWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
        Set GetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(path & wbName)
    End If
End Function
```