Runtime error 9: subscript out of range in one remote desktop but not others
My macro works on all (required) remote desktops except one.
That leads me to believe that my code is fine.
wsCurrentworksheet.Active
File = Cells(7, 4)
Path = Cells(7, 5)

ChDrive Left(Path, 1)
ChDir Path

Set wbMyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=File, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
wbMyWorkbook.Activate
Set wsMyWorksheet = wbMyWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '*gives runtime error 9*
wsMyWorksheet.Activate

The Set wsMyWorksheet line gives

runtime error 9: subscript out of range

I know the path is fine because it does open the workbook being called.
A temporary and inefficient "fix" is to repeat this part of the code twice:
Set wbMyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=File, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
wbMyWorkbook.Activate

Set wbMyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=File, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
wbMyWorkbook.Activate

Set wsMyWorksheet = wbMyWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
wsMyWorksheet.Activate

What does this tell me and how can I fix it?

Does the worksheet exist in the connected remote desktop? Does this desktop use an other UI language?

All of them are the same and yeah it exists in all remote desktops. It even opens the workbook in the one where it is giving an error.

The only ways that the error you describe can happen is if either a) the WorkBook has no Worksheets, or b) there is no Sheet1 in the WorkSheet.

Someone has renamed "Sheet1" in one of your environments

Are you sure the sheet is called "Sheet1"?

It is called "Sheet1". Its a standard report on a shared drive.

Maybe wbMyWorkbook is pointing to the wrong workbook?  It was possible in some older versions of Excel that if a file was already open and you called Workbooks.Open on that same file, it would end up assigning the reference to a different (open) workbook.

Also there's really no need to use ChDrive/ChDir if you have the full path to the file you want to open...

"wrong workbook" issue  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73953499/478884   This is fixed in recent versions of Excel though I think.

I added an edit, can someone help clarify why this might fix it and what does it mean? Why is it detecting Sheet1 in the second part of the code but not the first?

What version of Excel does the problem occur with?

This is a safer way if you have non-current Excel versions:
    Dim wbMyWorkbook As Workbook, wbPath As String, wbName As String
    
    wbPath = "C:\Temp\"   'for example
    wbName = "Data.xlsx"  'include the extension
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if not open
    Set wbMyWorkbook = Workbooks(wbName) 'already open?
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    
    If wbMyWorkbook Is Nothing Then 'if not already open then open it
        'no need for ChDrive/ChDir if you use the full path
        Set wbMyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbPath & wbName, _
                                   UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    End If


I tried this, I am getting the same error. I am using the latest version of office 365.

the only difference is that the excel where it doesn't work is 32 bits and the other ones are 64 bits

Maybe check what's in Tools >> References in the VB editor and see if there are any issues there?  I've never seen an error like that.  When the error pops up is there a "Debug" button?   If No, try setting the VBA error handling to "Break in class module"

I figured it out. Opening the workbook and setting it at the same time was causing some confusion because it was referencing another workbook for some strange reason but I broke up that line into 2 separate codes and it works fine. Thanks for helping!
